# Android Studio 4.0 WARN error on launch from terminal might be causing UI problems? (Ubuntu 20,04)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

This is a fresh install of Android Studio 4.0 and when I launch it from the terminal, it gives me this error. Android Studio launches normally and I can do my work but I have noticed something strange with the UI. I think the errors shown below might have something to do with it but I'm not sure.

Can the error shown below affect me greatly? Is the UI bugging out related to this?

Screenshots:
[Menu options are cut off by the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wof7g.png)
[An attempt to extend the window to see other options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKscb.png)

Video demonstration: https://streamable.com/ulu0g4

```
2020-06-11 18:52:21,207 [    737]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - List.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2020-06-11 18:52:21,207 [    737]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Table.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2020-06-11 18:52:21,207 [    737]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Tree.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2020-06-11 18:52:21,255 [    785]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk]
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

0. Open Android Studio

[image: Android Studio Home Screen]

Configure > Plugins

In Marketplace tab search for ReSharper Keymap and install it.

You can also update the installed plugins from the Installed tab, if you ever face any issues of incompatible plugins.